# Generic factory - expect certain constructor

Tags: c#, generics, factory

I want to provide a factory for a certain type of class restricted by a generic constraint, however I need to make sure that the *product* to create has a certain constructor in order to make my factory work.

```
public interface IFactory<TProduct>
    where TProduct: class, IMyRestriction
{

    TProduct Create();

}
```

Class which implements IMyRestriction:

```
public class MyRestriction : IMyRestriction {

    public MyRestriction(IArgumentType1 arg1, IArgumentType2 arg2) {
        ...
    }

}
```

which would make this work...

```
public class MyFactory<TProduct> : IFactory<TProduct>
    where TProduct: class, IMyRestriction
{

    public TProduct Create() {
        // args provided by factory constructor
        Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(TProduct), arg1, arg2); 
    }

}
```

... however not for a class like this:

```
public class MyDerivedRestriction : MyRestriction {

    public MyDerivedRestriction()
        : base(null, null)
    {

    }

}
```

The only way I'm able to restrict on a certain constructor using generics is with the new() constraint, but that doesn't make sense in this case.

Comment: Are you sure you shouldn't be using an IoC Container such as [`Autofac`](http://autofac.org/) or [`StructureMap`](http://docs.structuremap.net/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've essentially answered your own question -as you know the only type of constraint controlling the constructer is a parameterless one.

The only option left then is to use some sort of Initialization method in place of a constructor, and the logic you would usually do in the constructor do in the `Init` method

```
interface IMyRestriction
{
   // use whichever arguments you wanted for construction
   void Init(string myParam1, string myParam2)
}

public class MyFactory<TProduct> : IFactory<TProduct>
    where TProduct: class, IMyRestriction, new()
{

    public TProduct Create() {
       TProduct p = new TProduct(); 
        p.Init(arg1,arg2);
        return p;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need to create different classes with different constructor signatures, you are probably looking for an [Abstract Factory](http://www.dofactory.com/net/abstract-factory-design-pattern) pattern, where each entity class has its own implementation of the Factory interface:

```
#region Restriction Types

public class MyRestriction : IMyRestriction {
    public MyRestriction(IArgumentType1 arg1, IArgumentType2 arg2) {
        ...
    }
}

public class MyDerivedRestriction : MyRestriction {
    public MyDerivedRestriction()
        : base(null, null)
    {
    }
}

#endregion

#region Factory interface

public interface IFactory<TProduct>
    where TProduct: class, IMyRestriction
{
    TProduct Create();
}

#endregion

#region Factory implementations for each entity

public class MyRestrictionFactory : IFactory<MyRestriction>
{
    public MyRestriction Create()
    {
        // args provided by factory constructor
        return new MyRestriction(arg1, arg2); 
    }
}

public class MyDerivedRestrictionFactory : IFactory<MyDerivedRestriction>
{
    public MyDerivedRestriction Create()
    {
        return new MyDerivedRestriction(); 
    }
}

#endregion
```

This may seem like creating more code, but each factory class can be tiny, plus it provides more type-safety and is more flexible, as the factory can deal with the idiosyncrasies of its entity.

As an extension of this pattern, people often add interfaces for each factory, to make it nicer to register in an IOC container and provide more abstraction, but you may not need this in your case. For example:

```
// this gets resolved in DI, so the IFactory<T> part is abstracted away
public interface IMyRestrictionFactory
{
    MyRestriction Create();
}

public class MyRestrictionFactory : IFactory<MyRestriction>, IMyRestrictionFactory
{
    public MyRestriction Create()
    {
        // args provided by factory constructor
        return new MyRestriction(arg1, arg2); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In C# you can't put generic constraints, which define desired signature of constructor, except `new()` (parameterless constructor).

The best you can do here is either rely on run-time exceptions, or re-write initialization logic to use properties of `IMyRestriction` instead of constructor arguments:

```
interface IMyRestriction
{
    IArgumentType1 Property1 { get; set; }
    IArgumentType2 Property2 { get; set; }
}

public class MyFactory<TProduct> : IFactory<TProduct>
    where TProduct : class, IMyRestriction, new()
{
    public TProduct Create()
    {
        var product = new TProduct();

        product.Property1 = arg1;
        product.Property2 = arg2;

        return product;
    }

}
```

Comment: I also thought about properties, however the arguments need to present when the product gets constructed, e.g. are not allowed to be set via properties later because they would mess up with the logic of the product.

Comment: @xvdiff: you may consider to use lazy initialization of product. It really depends on the nature of your entities an business logic.